# CSS Selector: Select TR where TD contains special value

Tags: jquery, css, selector

I have a Table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            row4545
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            row22
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            row6767
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to set a background-color on the tr which contains the value row22 in a td.
Is it possible to select it somehow with CSS?

PS: I use jQuery.

Comment: contains or equal row22?

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with it? Do you want to select it with CSS or jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible only with css...

Comment: Is the content fixed or dynamic? If it's fixed - then just add a class on those elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('tr td').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "row22";
}).parent().css('background-color', 'blue')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/392g2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td').filter(function(){
     return $.trim($(this).text()) === "row22";
}).closest('tr').css('color','red');
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/jJWs2/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can write this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "td:contains(row22)").css("background-color","red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should Help..

```
$('tr td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "row22";
}).parent().css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("td:contains('row22')").filter(function(){        
        $.trim($(this).text()) == 'row22' ? $(this).parent().attr('style','background:red;') : '';
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
    <tr style="background:#000;">
        <td>
            row4545
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            row22
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            row6767
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```