# Change style of a cell if value is zero

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found how to do it with inputs.

```css
input[value="0"] {
  background-color:#F7ECEC;
    color:#f00;}
```

I want to do the same with table cells. Can someone help me?  Thx.

Comment: Do you mean depending of the content at the cell or to all table cells?

Comment: Depending on content, i'm getting values from database, and i want to change the cell border, or cell background with red color if the value from database displayed in cell is 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188896/css-selector-select-tr-where-td-contains-special-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code when you get the values from db on windows.load or in success from asynchronous call:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  if (parseInt(cells[i].textContent, 10) === 0) {
    cells[i].style.background = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```